# Visual Studio User Macros: $(X)

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 and have installed and since removed an old Windows 10 SDK (10158).  Sadly this has left my environment macros (the ones you have access to in all of the property sheets) with ghost directories relating to that version of the SDK that don't exist anymore ie:

```
$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10158.0\ucrt
```

This means my default environment now cant see Windows.h etc.  How can I edit/remove those 'macros' as I cant edit them in the Property Manager.  I've completely removed the Windows 10 SDKs that I had installed and Visual Studio 2015 itself and then reinstalled everything to the latest versions but sadly this didn't reset these settings so they must be in some shared location.  I've searched in the registry but to no avail either.

Anybody have any idea how I can get my environment working again?

Thanks

Comment: I've found that the UI for Visual Studio is so clunky, I always have more success editing project settings in a text editor.  I presume you can do the same for property sheets, although I don't have any experience doing that.  Maybe give it a try.

Comment: Its not the property sheets themselves as far as I can see, its the macros used in the property sheets which are wrong.  I could just go into my property sheets and remove all inherited values but which would stop the base macros being used in the Include Directories property ie $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath); but this seems like a lot of work that I'd continually have to do to all future projects.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this value was actually coming from my vcxproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{X}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>X</RootNamespace>
    <ProjectName>X</ProjectName>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10158.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10240.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It seems now the 'Target Platform Version' in the General options section sets WindowsTargetPlatformVersion in the final Visual Studio 2015 build rather than the TargetPlatformVersion in the RC Visual Studio 2015 build.

I found this out by tracing back through numerous .props and .targets files distributed throughout the 'Program Files x86' directory which build up the 'User Macros' we see in property options.

Manually changing TargetPlatformVersion to 10240 in Notepad fixed my issues.